When an embedded c program is created, why is there extra machine code around my compiled c program?
This C program blinks an LED attached to an AVR ATmega32u4.
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) // attach Interrupt Sub Routine to TIMER1
{
    // toggle LED
    PIND = (1 << PIND5); // #define PIND (*(volatile uint8_t* 0x29))
}


int main(void)
{
    sei(); // enable interrupts

    // setup Timer1
    TCCR1A = 0; // #define TCCR1A _SFR_MEM8(0x80)
    TCCR1B = (1 << CS12); // #define TCCR1B _SFR_MEM8(0x81) // #define CS12 2
    TIMSK1 = (1 << TOIE1); // #define TIMSK1 _SFR_MEM8(0x6F) // #define TOIE1 0
    
    DDRD = (1 << DDD5); // set PORTD (addr 0x2B) pin 5 to output

    // forever loop
    for (;;){ 
        asm("nop");
    }
}

Here is the compiled assembly using avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega32u4 -fverbose-asm -S main.c with some added comments:

__vector_20: ; ISR label
/* start prologue */
    ...
    lds r0,95 ; 95 = 0x5F = (SREG) : CLI()
    ...
    ldi r24,lo8(41) ; r24 = 0x29 (addr of PIND)
    ldi r25,0
    ldi r18,lo8(32) ; r18 = 0b0010 0000 (1 << PIND5)
    movw r30,r24    ; Z = [r24:r25] (addr of PIND)
    /* toggle LED */
    st Z,r18        ; (*(uint16* 0x29)) = (1 << PIND5) 
    nop
/* epilogue start */
    ...
    reti ; return 
 ;  "main.c"
    sei
    ldi r24,lo8(-128) ; r24 = 0x80
    ldi r25,0
    movw r30,r24      ; Z = [r24:25]
    st Z,__zero_reg__ ; TCCR1A = 0
    ldi r24,lo8(-127) ; r24 = 0x81
    ldi r25,0
    ldi r18,lo8(4)    ; r18 = 0x04 = (1 << CS12)
    movw r30,r24      ; Z = r[24:25]
    st Z,r18      ; TCCR1B = (1 << CS12)
    ldi r24,lo8(111)  ; r24 = 0x6F
    ldi r25,0
    ldi r18,lo8(1)    ; r18 = 0x01
    movw r30,r24      ; Z pointer = 0x6F
    st Z,r18          ; 
    ldi r24,lo8(42)   ; 
    ldi r25,0
    ldi r18,lo8(32)
    movw r30,r24
    st Z,r18
.L3:
/* #APP */
 ;  30 "main.c" 1
    nop
 ;  0 "" 2
/* #NOAPP */

When I run avr-objdump -D main.out > main.s I get many more lines of assembly many of them looking like this:
main.out:     file format elf32-avr


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__vectors>:
   0:   0c 94 56 00     jmp 0xac    ; 0xac <__ctors_end>
   4:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
   8:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
   c:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
  10:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
  14:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
  18:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
...
  40:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
  44:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
  48:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
  4c:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
  50:   0c 94 62 00     jmp 0xc4    ; 0xc4 <__vector_20>
  54:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
  58:   0c 94 60 00     jmp 0xc0    ; 0xc0 <__bad_interrupt>
...
Disassembly of section .stab:

00000000 <.stab>:
   0:   01 00           .word   0x0001  ; ????
   2:   00 00           nop
   4:   00 00           nop
   6:   73 00           .word   0x0073  ; ????
   8:   9c 0c           add r9, r12
   a:   00 00           nop
   c:   08 00           .word   0x0008  ; ????
   e:   00 00           nop
  10:   64 00           .word   0x0064  ; ????
  12:   02 00           .word   0x0002  ; ????
  14:   c4 00           .word   0x00c4  ; ????
  16:   00 00           nop
  18:   01 00           .word   0x0001  ; ????
  1a:   00 00           nop
  1c:   64 00           .word   0x0064  ; ????
  1e:   02 00           .word   0x0002  ; ????
  20:   c4 00           .word   0x00c4  ; ????
...

Disassembly of section .stabstr:

00000000 <.stabstr>:
   0:   00 6d           ori r16, 0xD0   ; 208
   2:   61 69           ori r22, 0x91   ; 145
   4:   6e 2e           mov r6, r30
   6:   63 00           .word   0x0063  ; ????
   8:   2f 68           ori r18, 0x8F   ; 143
   a:   6f 6d           ori r22, 0xDF   ; 223
   c:   65 2f           mov r22, r21
   e:   62 65           ori r22, 0x52   ; 82
  10:   73 74           andi    r23, 0x43   ; 67
  12:   2f 50           subi    r18, 0x0F   ; 15
  14:   72 6f           ori r23, 0xF2   ; 242
  16:   6a 65           ori r22, 0x5A   ; 90
  18:   63 74           andi    r22, 0x43   ; 67
  1a:   73 2f           mov r23, r19
  1c:   61 76           andi    r22, 0x61   ; 97
  1e:   72 2d           mov r23, r2
  20:   6d 6b           ori r22, 0xBD   ; 189
  22:   62 2f           mov r22, r18
  24:   64 65           ori r22, 0x54   ; 84
  26:   6d 6f           ori r22, 0xFD   ; 253
  28:   2f 62           ori r18, 0x2F   ; 47
  2a:   6c 69           ori r22, 0x9C   ; 156
  2c:   6e 6b           ori r22, 0xBE   ; 190
  2e:   79 2f           mov r23, r25
  30:   00 67           ori r16, 0x70   ; 112
  32:   63 63           ori r22, 0x33   ; 51
  34:   32 5f           subi    r19, 0xF2   ; 242
...
  38:   32 75           andi    r19, 0x52   ; 82
  3a:   34 00           .word   0x0034  ; ????
  3c:   00 00           nop
    ...

Disassembly of section .debug_info:

00000000 <.debug_info>:
   0:   f0 09           sbc r31, r0
   2:   00 00           nop
   4:   02 00           .word   0x0002  ; ????
   6:   00 00           nop
   8:   00 00           nop
   a:   04 01           movw    r0, r8
    ...
  14:   02 0f           add r16, r18
  16:   00 00           nop
  18:   00 01           movw    r0, r0
  1a:   08 03           fmul    r16, r16
  1c:   17 00           .word   0x0017  ; ????
  1e:   00 00           nop
  20:   02 07           cpc r16, r18
...
9ea:    00 00           nop
 9ec:   01 05           cpc r16, r1
 9ee:   03 d7           rcall   .+3590      ; 0x17f6 <__stack+0xcf7>
 9f0:   00 80           ld  r0, Z
...

Disassembly of section .debug_abbrev:

00000000 <.debug_abbrev>:
   0:   01 11           cpse    r16, r1
   2:   01 25           eor r16, r1
   4:   0e 10           cpse    r0, r14
   6:   06 00           .word   0x0006  ; ????
   8:   00 02           muls    r16, r16
   a:   24 00           .word   0x0024  ; ????
   c:   03 0e           add r0, r19
   e:   0b 0b           sbc r16, r27
  10:   3e 0b           sbc r19, r30
  12:   00 00           nop
  14:   03 24           eor r0, r3
  16:   00 03           mulsu   r16, r16
  18:   0e 0b           sbc r16, r30
  1a:   0b 3e           cpi r16, 0xEB   ; 235
  1c:   0b 00           .word   0x000b  ; ????
  1e:   00 04           cpc r0, r0
  20:   01 01           movw    r0, r2
  22:   49 13           cpse    r20, r25
  24:   00 00           nop
  26:   05 21           and r16, r5
...
 95e:   0b 3b           cpi r16, 0xBB   ; 187
 960:   0b 49           sbci    r16, 0x9B   ; 155
 962:   13 3f           cpi r17, 0xF3   ; 243
 964:   0c 02           muls    r16, r28
 966:   0a 00           .word   0x000a  ; ????
...

Disassembly of section .debug_line:

00000000 <.debug_line>:
   0:   16 00           .word   0x0016  ; ????
   2:   00 00           nop
   4:   02 00           .word   0x0002  ; ????
   6:   10 00           .word   0x0010  ; ????
   8:   00 00           nop
   a:   02 01           movw    r0, r4
   c:   fb 0e           add r15, r27
   e:   0a 00           .word   0x000a  ; ????
  10:   01 01           movw    r0, r2
  12:   01 01           movw    r0, r2
  14:   00 00           nop
  16:   00 01           movw    r0, r0
...

Disassembly of section .debug_str:

00000000 <.debug_str>:
   0:   61 76           andi    r22, 0x61   ; 97
   2:   72 2d           mov r23, r2
   4:   6c 69           ori r22, 0x9C   ; 156
   6:   62 63           ori r22, 0x32   ; 50
   8:   20 32           cpi r18, 0x20   ; 32
   a:   2e 30           cpi r18, 0x0E   ; 14
   c:   2e 30           cpi r18, 0x0E   ; 14
   e:   00 75           andi    r16, 0x50   ; 80
  10:   69 6e           ori r22, 0xE9   ; 233
  12:   74 38           cpi r23, 0x84   ; 132
  14:   5f 74           andi    r21, 0x4F   ; 79
  16:   00 75           andi    r16, 0x50   ; 80
  18:   69 6e           ori r22, 0xE9   ; 233
  1a:   74 31           cpi r23, 0x14   ; 20
  1c:   36 5f           subi    r19, 0xF6   ; 246
  1e:   74 00           .word   0x0074  ; ????
...


Why is this? What are these other parts outside of the  and <__vector_20> ISR sections? Is there a good resource to explain what is happening?
Thank you!

The __vectors is the interrupt vector table. Consult AVR manual. The rest is debug info, can be turned off. Those are not code but data, hence disassembling them is pointless.

Your main.out won't just have the contents of main.o in it. There will be some other code, probably from some assembly language startup files, in there. Look at your build scripts/process to see what the linker actually puts into the final binary.

Add the -v flag to the avr-gcc command line.  That should show you what is being executed on your behalf — and should list some extra files, etc.

are you looking for what all of it means or what an elf or other container contains (other than code)?   objdump tries to disassemble everything including symbol tables, vector table entries, etc.   by design.  but if you want to see what code is produced that is the tool you use and you need -D to see the non .text parts.  -d only shows a portion of the code produced picture.   If you are confused about all of it including the code and data parts, that is a longer answer.

If it is just about containers file formats like the elf file format then just read up on those.  The elf file format which I think you can even find on wikipedia, only describes the container, how the compiler/linker uses it is specific to the toolchain.  but tools like readelf will give you a bit of a clue.  IMO it is both easy and very educational to write your own tool from scratch to rip apart an elf file into the various sections, a lazy sunday afternoons work that will forever change your life.


When I run avr-objdump -D main.out > main.s I get many more lines of assembly many of them looking like this:
00000000 <__vectors>:

This is the interrupt vector table.  It is included an all applications, except with -nostartfiles (in which case the resulting program is broken and will malfunction).

Disassembly of section .stab:

This is debug information. It is displayed due to objdump -D which disassembles everything, including stuff that makes no sense to disassemble, and that will not be part of the code loaded onto the device (like debug info).

Disassembly of section .stabstr:
Disassembly of section .debug_info:
Disassembly of section .debug_abbrev: 
Disassembly of section .debug_line:
Disassembly of section .debug_str:

Same due to objdump -D

Why is this?

Because everything present in the ELF file is disassembled.  Maybe objdump -d is what you are looking for?

why is there extra machine code around my compiled C program?

This is because extra code is needed which is pulled in from libraries.  Amongst them:

Code to initialize the .data and .bss sections which hold data in static storage.  Conforming C/C++ implementations require that data in static storage is initialized.  Notice that this code is only linked when needed.  Plus, depending on the AVR device you are using, .rodata has to be initialized, too, because it might be located in RAM.

Code to run static constructors and functions declared with attribute __constructor__.

Code to run static destructors, functions declared with attribute __destructor__ and functions registered with atexit.

Code to set __zero_reg__ to 0.  Code to set SP according to symbol __stack.

Code for functions that is too expensive to be emit in-line, like code for floating-point arithmetic, division, multiplication, and many others.

Code for the interrupt vector table in .vectors as already explained above.


For example, when you have code like
int two = 2;

then somebody has to initialize that variable so that when main begins, two actually has a value of 2.  The somebody is the extra code, start-up code from libgcc, specifically code from __do_copy_data in this example.

main.out is an ELF format object file containing metadata that is loaded by the debugger on the development host, but not part of the target binary image. Your incorrect use of objdump is giving you a false impression that that is target code rather than host metadata I think.
Rather than using disassembly, request the linker generate a map file.  That will be much clearer than reverse engineering with objdump.  You will find processor and C runtime initialisation code which runs between reset and main.
GCC normally links a module crt0.o containing necessary start-up code.  You will likely find in your toolchain something called crt0.s, that is the startup code assembly source (so you can customise it).
The start-up code does a number of things including:

Setting the initial stack pointer
Static data initialisation
If C++ code included, invoking static object constructors.
Runtime library initialisation.
Jump to main()


The only reason objdump is giving a false impression is the -D switch which forces it to "disassemble the contents of all sections, not just those expected to contain instructions".

@Jester Your knowledge of the tool exceeds mine. On the few occasions I use it I RTFM ;-).  I still maintain that the link map makes more sense in this context.  Either way there is no substitute for knowing how to use the tools appropriately/correctly as you suggest.  I am not however answering a question about how to use objdump, but rather the more general question of what ends up in a link other than your own code.

Yeah no problem just wanted to defend the honor of objdump :)

@Jester - Point accepted. Edited accordingly.
